# How to rename an uploaded file in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-rename

I'm uploading a file to the server in PHP. Now I want to rename the file to the new name, but I couldn't get it done. The proposed new name of file will be composed of the value from one associative array and a variable name. For achieving that I did following code but not able to get the newly named file. My code is as follows:

```
$test_pack_id  = md5(uniqid($this->hash_secret));


    if(!empty($test_pack_id )){
                  $package_image_file = $form_image_data['test_pack_image']['name'];

                  $nwName = rename($package_image_file,$form_data['test_pack_name'].$test_pack_id);  
                  echo $nwName; die;
                }
```

Can anyone help me on how to rename a file in PHP? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: Are you renaming the file after upload or inbetween upload?

Comment: @Orangepill: Now I'm getting the file name in variable  $package_image_file. I just want to rename that file. Can you help me in this?

Comment: @phpLover Jayram has your answer below.

Answer (score 2):

bool rename ( string $oldname , string $newname [, resource $context ] )

Note:
The old name. The wrapper used in oldname must match the wrapper used in newname.

Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

```
<?php
rename("old", "new");
?>
```

Check this link too
http://www.codersmount.com/2011/07/smart-way-for-renaming-uploaded-files-using-php/

Comment: Your given link is really useful for me. But the answer you given was just a opy paste from PHP manual, please avoid doing such things in future.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a print_r or var_dump on $form_data because I suspect that the data being passed to 'test_pack_name' is incorrect and causing the rename to fail. I would also included swapnesh's suggestion to put in a conditional *if* to report on the success or failure of the rename to provide you additional debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

PHP `rename();` function

```
rename ("123", "abc");
rename ("oldname", "newname");
```

Comment: But it's not returning anything.

Comment: maybe there's nothing to rename in the first place, meaning there's a problem before this, try (instead of renaming), just echo the variable to test if this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

PHP `rename()`  returns `true` or `false`

so u can check if via `if` statement

```
if(rename())
echo "Success";
else
echo "failure";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rename` as others have suggested. OR just simply rename the file using the time at which it was uploaded. This is what i usually do. Take a look:

```
//First separate the original file name from its extension
list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
//rename it with its timestamp.
$actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
```

Hope this helps.